# An array is undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am actually trying to retrieve something for a sqlite database and store the results in an array. So I create an array and pass it as an argument to the function. Then after the function returns, the array remains undefined. What is the problem with that?

```
function initGraphView()
{
   var resultsArray=new Array(12);
   getGraphData(defaultQueryString,resultsArray);
   alert(resultsArray[0]); //undefined
}
```

```
    getGraphData=function(queryString,resultsArray)
{
dbConnection.transaction(function(tx){
 tx.executeSql(queryString, [],
    function(SQLTransaction, data)
    {
        for(var i=0;i
```

Comment: please post your full getGraphData function and also usually arrays are initialized like `var resultsArray = [];`

Comment: @Erik, yes its running on Google chrome

Comment: @errorhandler it is the entire function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what the getGraphData function is doing, but it looks like it's asynchronous. See the function passed into dbConnection.transaction? That's probably a callback that executes once the operation is complete, at some later time. You will need to handle the result from there instead.

Also, the function is passed the array as parameter 'anArray', but you're not using that parameter, you're using 'resultsArray'. Since that isn't defined in that scope, it's not the same array you think.

Answer (score 1):

you are not assigning the return value of function `getGraphData` to any variable.

`resultsArray = getGraphData(defaultQueryString,resultsArray);`

```
function initGraphView()
{
   var resultsArray=new Array(12);
   resultsArray= getGraphData(defaultQueryString,resultsArray);
   alert(resultsArray[0]); // undefined.
}




getGraphData=function(queryString,anArray)
{
dbConnection.transaction(function(tx){
 tx.executeSql(queryString, [],
    function(SQLTransaction, data)
    {
      for(var i=0;i<data.rows.length;i++)
      {
        var row = data.rows.item(i);
        var aName = row[name];
        var aMonth=row[month];
        var total=row[totalAmount];
        var aCategoryName=row[categoryName];
        anArray[parseInt(aMonth)]=parseFloat(total);
      }
    }
  )
});

return anArray;  // use return statement here
}
```

Comment: tried this out, it doesn't work. I guess its because of the asynchronous behavior in which the request is processed.

Comment: ur answer is right in the normal situation, but since i was using this script to fetch a data from a database, the call to it was asynchronous and thus the array came out to be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know javascript well but there is something called passByValue and PassByReference...  maybe try setting what you return, something like:

```
    vatAdded=addVAT(orderTotal)

    function addVAT(value){
      var newValue
      newValue=value*1.07
      return newValue
    }
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

`resultsArray` from `initGraphView` is not visible in the `getGraphData` function object.

You need to change `anArray` to `resultsArray`.